# Multiple links in SwiftUI using Markdown

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I would like to make a Text with 2 hyperlinks (Terms of Use and Privacy Policy) using markdown. But it seems like markdown link works only for the first line. If Privacy Policy text will be moved to second line, link for Privacy Policy will not be tappable. How can I make it work?

```
let termsAndPrivacyText = "Read [Terms of Use](https://example.com) and [Privacy Policy](https://example.com)."
Text(.init(termsAndPrivacyText))
```

Comment: how did you move privacy policy to the second line?

Answer (score 1):

either like this:

```
let termsAndPrivacyText = try! AttributedString(markdown: "Read [Terms of Use](https://example.com) and [Privacy Policy](https://example.com).")
Text(termsAndPrivacyText)
```

or directly:

```
Text("Read [Terms of Use](https://example.com) and [Privacy Policy](https://apple.com).")
```